# jquery in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery

Does anyone have any examples of how to make a jQuery get from a Lightning component using code similar to the below where the data will be returned from SOQL query in Salesforce

jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/MCS/GetCar', 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",

I am already aware of how to import the jquery library using ltng:require and creating an @AuraEnabled method in Apex but it was wiring the rest together I was unsure about, I am relatively new to Lightning although aware of the basics.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For client/server communication you'll want to go through the standard Aura APIs instead of `jQuery.ajax()`. I recommend going through the full [Develop for Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trail/lex_dev) Trailhead module if you're new to Lightning component development. Or if you've already gone through that, I'd revisit the [Connect to Salesforce with Server-Side Controllers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/lex_dev/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server) section.

You were on the right track with the `@AuraEnabled` method. Instead of calling `ajax()` though you'll want to create an Aura action by getting it from your component instance `var action = component.get("c.getExpenses");`, and then firing it via enqueueAction `$A.enqueueAction(action);`. See the Trailhead module for the full example and how to handle the response.